# Microsoft Planetary Computer, grouping Sentinel 1 data by solar day

Tags: group-by

I am attempting to extract sentinel 1 data from Microsoft Planetary Computer, unfortunately the data returned is counting separate swaths as separate time slices. I wish to group the time slices by solar day to eliminate this problem, akin to DEA Sandbox group_by='solar_day', function.

Could someone please help this novice correct the below code to group the sentinel 1 data outputs by solar day in MPC?

```
#Define bounding box for area of interest
bbox = [149.703, -36.064, 150.716, -35.071]
search = catalog.search(collections=["sentinel-1-rtc"], bbox=bbox, datetime="2020-02-07/2020-02-11",
)

# Create a DataFrame with a 'SolarDay' column
data = {'Timestamp': ['2020-02-07', '2020-02-08', '2020-02-09', '2020-02-10', '2020-02-11']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df['SolarDay'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.dayofyear

grouped=df.groupby("SolarDay").max()
    

items = search.items()


print(f"Found {len(items)} items")
item = items[0]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 18
     12 grouped=df.groupby("SolarDay").max()
     15 items = search.items()
---> 18 print(f"Found {len(items)} items")
     19 item = items[0]

TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```